# WPF Trigger a Command at end of animation

Tags: wpf, animation, command, triggers

How can I trigger a Command in my ViewModel at the end of an animation/storyboard using XAML only.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Command property in your Model and manually execute command on [Animation Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) event

Comment: Yea, I think because Annimation classes don't have any command property

Comment: I can register for the event in a trigger but I can not start the command in a trigger. At least I dont't see how.

Comment: do you have command property in model? if(model.command.CanExecute) model.Command.Execute(...);

Comment: I have that in the VIEWModel yes.

Comment: then you can execute it manually as I mentioned in last comment

Comment: Yes but how do I wire up the AnimationCompleted Event with my ViewModel. I would not want to do it in the code behind. That's why I said "xaml only".

Comment: sometimes you should write some glue code in code behind,if it is not breaking model's testing functionality of course, not every requirement is possible to implement only with binding, for example when you want to show message box to verify user choice the better place to do that is code behind